# What is the meaning of comma operators in Python?

Tags: python

basically I missed school during a year for personal reasons, so now we're doing python and I have little to no idea of what's going on. I did understand the basics of functions, but now I need to solve this code:
The second part of the code is what I don't understand.

```
def determinant(x1,y1,x2,y2)
return x1*y2-y1*x2

def alignement(xA,yA,xB,yB,xC,yC):
    x1,y1=xB-xA,yB-yA
    x2,y2=xC-xA,yC-yA
    if determinant(x1,y1,x2,y2)==0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: By the way; I see that you're new, if one of our answers helps you out; mark it as correct so people know when they're looking around :)

Comment: Take a look at this: https://treyhunner.com/2018/03/tuple-unpacking-improves-python-code-readability/

Answer (score 1):

This coma:

```py
x1, y1=xB - xA, yB - yA
```

is the same as

```py
x1 = xB - Xa
y1 = yB - yA
```

The comas at the function declaration:

```py
def determinant(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    pass  # or

def alignement(xA, yA, xB, yB, xC, yC):
    pass
```

are just for splitting the variables, in some programming languages you do not need parentheses or comas, for instance if F# can be:

```ml
let determinant x1 y1 x2 y2 = // something
let sum a b = a + b
and you can call it:
sum 2 3 // will result in 5
```

Answer (score 0):

The comma in python simply indicates a new parameter or value being passed to a function, list or dictionary. An example with functions being:

```
def foo(param1, param2):
    print(param1, param2)

variable1 = "there"

foo("hello", variable1)
```

Then with lists:

```
list1 = ["hello", 1, "there", 2]
```

Then with dictionaries:

```
dict1 = {
    "hello" : "there",
    "foo" : 3
}
```

In your example, it would help to add some spacing (which I will do, and also explain)

I will go over just one line which should explain the rest.

```
x1, y1 = xB-xA, yB-yA
```

So here; `x1` will be equal to `xB-xA`, and `y1` will be equal to `yB-yA` because of how the commas are structured. The sides match, and this can scale up.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your question is about these lines:

```py
x1, y1 = xB-xA, yB-yA
x2, y2 = xC-xA, yC-yA
```

The comma operator in Python creates a [tuple](https://realpython.com/python-lists-tuples/). In this case, it is used to perform multiple assignment. The lines above are equivalent to writing:

```py
x1 = xB-xA
y1 = yB-yA
x2 = xC-xA
y2 = yC-yA
```

It uses a mechanism called tuple unpacking, you can read about it [here](https://treyhunner.com/2018/03/tuple-unpacking-improves-python-code-readability/).